# What is known about this specialization of the falling factorial involving primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, products

The falling (descending) factorial $x^\underline n$ for $n,x\in\mathbb N, x>0$ is defined as:

$$x^\underline n = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k).$$

What is known about the specialization of the falling factorial in which the summands are the primes, i.e.,

$$
x^\underline {\overline{n}} = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x-p_k),
$$

where $p_k$ is the $k ^{\rm th}$ prime?

Comment: Well, $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(x-p_k)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n-1$. So, for large $x$ it is asymptotic to $x^{n-1}$. I believe you are after something else?

Comment: I really think you need to be more specific as to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizations of the rising/falling factorial have been previously studied; see e.g. [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04708) or [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Generalizations).

Quoting some of the results from those articles, we have:
$\newcommand{\stirling}{\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}}$
Let $\stirling{n}{k}$ denote the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ in the $n$th falling prime factorial. Then the coefficients satisfy the following relation for $n\geq 1$:
$$\stirling{n}{k}=\stirling{n-1}{k-1}-p_{n-1}\stirling{n-1}{k}$$

We also have interesting identities on the prime harmonic numbers such as:
$$\left(\prod_{j=1}^n p_j^2\right)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k^2}=\stirling{n+1}{2}^2-2\stirling{n+1}{1}\stirling{n+1}{3}$$

See the references for a lot of relations along those lines.

Comment: Do those results depend on the $p_k$ being primes?

Comment: No, these are general results for any $p_k$. I do not know of results that are only true for $p_k$ being the primes, other than properties that are different for every sequence such as asymptotics.

Comment: @GrantB. Ouf, 4 minutes before the bounty expires... :) Thank you for your answer and those links!